# How do I get IntelliSense for XML tags in VS2019?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, visual-studio-2019

I remember in old versions of Visual Studio, I could get IntelliSense for XML tags - if I add a schema to an XML document, I'd be able to type the beginning of a tag and see the tag completed for me. However this doesn't seem to work in VS2019; I also tried adding the schema through the document's properties page and of course that didn't do anything either. Is this feature broken in VS2019 or is there some trick to making it work?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably state this is for VB.NET.

An example of how this used to work is:

```
Imports <xmlns:abc="http://microsoft.com/example/schemas/1.0">

Sub Example
    Dim doc = XDocument.Load("sample.xml")
    Dim element = doc.<>
End Sub
```

The IntelliSense used to kick in after the first angle bracket (<) was typed. An xsd file was in the project so IntelliSense could read the xml schema and suggest element names.